# How can I get the data from table1 which is not inside table2? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I want to produce a dropdown of choices from table1. But if the data is existing in table2 I will not include it in the choices. I'm aware about the outer excluding join but I can't implement it in CodeIgniter. Do I have other choice rather than implementing the Outer Excluding Join in CodeIgniter? I'm currently using CodeIgniter3. This is my code so far. I'm trying to get the items in the inventory table which is not in the inven_trans table.

```
$this->db->select('brand')
        ->from('inventory')
        ->join('inven_trans', 'inventory.brand = inven_trans.brand', 'inner')
        ->where("NOT EXISTS( SELECT brand FROM inven_trans WHERE inventory.brand = inven_trans.brand)");
```

inventory

- invenID
- brand
- quantity
- product_num

inven_trans

- intransID
- invenID
- brand
- datereleased
- datereturned

EDIT
The code is working now although after adding another where clause it seems like it is not functioning (the where clause). This question is now closed but if someone is willing to help me I'll gladly accept it. The code is this

```
$data = $this->db
    ->select("*")
    ->from("inventory")
    ->where("brand NOT IN (SELECT brand FROM ha_inventory_trans WHERE date_returned != '00 00 0000')", NULL, FALSE)
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

I want to output the list of brand that has not been returned( date_returned is NULL or 0000 00 00)

Comment: Why do you store similar record on two tables, is it right? In Codeigniter you can use join like this: `$CI->db->join('tbl1', 'tbl1._id = tbl2._id', 'left');`

Comment: Do you know, if you want get real help here, ask a precise question and show us what you've got so far! )))

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov edited

Comment: Could you add your expected result, please?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov The brands from the inven_trans is from the inventory table. I want to output the brands from the inventory table which is not in the inven_trans table. (inven_trans is inventory_transaction)

Comment: Add some data of your tables/

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov edited

Comment: A type of the `date_returned` is date , datetime or timestamp?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov its a DATE. I edited the format into 0000 00 00 while saving in the database but the format in the webpage is 00 00 0000. Tried both but neither of them is working

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov tried using that but it just returns all the value of brand form table inventory. I also tried date_returned = '0000 00 00' and I got the same output

Comment: did you use `0000-00-00`? with `-` dash

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov it worked love u lot bro.Thanks

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use sub-queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM inventory
WHERE brand NOT IN (SELECT brand
                    FROM inven_trans
                    WHERE date_returned <> '0000-00-00')
```

Or using CI's active record:

```
$this->db
  ->select("*")
  ->from("inventory")
  ->where("brand NOT IN (SELECT brand FROM inven_trans WHERE date_returned <> '0000-00-00')", NULL, FALSE)
  ->get()
  ->result_array();
```

Comment: I tried to use that with this code and a foreach but i didnt have any result neither error. it only shows blank page

$data = $this->db
            ->select("*")
            ->from("inventory")
            ->where("brand NOT IN (SELECT brand FROM inven_trans)", NULL, FALSE);
        $all_inventory = @$data['inventory'];
        $output['inventory'] = array('' => '- Select Item -'

Comment: @goaty: i edited try again. I just thought that you'll figure out to complete the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Figured out the other. Sorry I tend to reply 1st before figuring things out

Comment: @goaty does it worked? if yes, great! I was glad to help

Comment: @goaty don't forget to upvote usefull questions and answers )))

Comment: Can I ask you another question? Did I addded the where clause correctly here? ("brand NOT IN (SELECT brand FROM ha_inventory_trans WHERE date_returned IS NOT NULL)

Comment: @goaty yes it is correct, also you can check `date_returned != ""`

Comment: I tried all of them date_returned != " " date_returned != "0000 00 00" date_returned IS NOT NULL but neither of them is not working. Anw thanks for your help

Comment: just edited. Thank you for your. This is my first post here.

Answer (score 0):

The only efficient way to really do it is by using JOIN. Check out [Codeigniter docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join) for how to use it if you're unsure...

Comment: i tried using join but it doesnt have the Outer Excluding Join.

Comment: @goaty can you post what you've done so far? or an idea of your table structure

Answer (score 0):

## This may help you out[Custom Query]

`$CustomQry = "SELECT brand FROM inventory INNER JOIN inven_trans ON (inventory.brand = inven_trans.brand) WHERE inventory.brand NOT IN (SELECT brand FROM inven_trans)";
    $result = $this->db->query($CustomQry);`